# Getting Firebase user token synchronously

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get a Firebase token to authenticate my calls to a Rest API. I can generate the tokens asynchronously with the following code.

```
    FirebaseUser mUser = App.getFirebaseAuth().getCurrentUser();
    if (mUser!=null) {
        mUser.getIdToken(false)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            ID_TOKEN = task.getResult().getToken();
                        } else {
                            Log.e(App.TAG, "Firebase Token task ended with error.");
                        }
                    }
                });
    } else {
        Log.i(App.TAG,"User is null, no Firebase Token available");
    }
```

The ID_TOKEN is a static string variable that holds the result. 
The issue is, I am constructing my request and adding the authentication headers.

```
        headers.put("Authentication",
                "Bearer  + ID_TOKEN);
```

The issue is, since the Firebase token is retrieved asynchronously, sometims the ID_TOKEN variable is empty. I tried forcing the thread to wait for the task using

Tasks.await(task)

But I get an exception saying await cannot be invoked in the main thread.

Is there any other way to get the token synchronously, or make the thread wait until the tasks finishes?

Comment: you could just try using a semaphore to make the main thread wait. But if the callback is called on the main thread, it will not work.

Probably not advisable, at all, to do that though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a really bad idea to force something to run on the main thread synchronously.  It could lock up your app and possibly cause it to ANR.  That's why Android it complains when you try to run `Tasks.await()` - it knows there could be a problem.

It's far better to learn how to do do asynchronous programming to do this the right way.  You will have to receive the token in the listener that you have to provide.

[Please read this blog](https://medium.com/@CodingDoug/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93) to learn more about why the Firebase APIs are asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks! Will read the blog and see if I can reformulate my code.

Comment: What if we want to get the token synchronously on a background thread which we can write manually?

Comment: @Vincent_Paing All Firebase APIs on Android that require I/O are asynchronous, there are no exceptions.

Comment: I just wrapped it in RxJava and using .blockingGet to get the token. It's hacky but it works I guess

Comment: @DougStevenson this is just assuming the developers of your api's clients are inexperienced. Any API should provide synchronous access first, because clients can have their own means of async access. Think rxjava, where it's much cleaner to wrap a synchronous api than async. You can still promote your custom way of async access (Tasks) via blog for inexperienced devs but not providing any way of sync is a bad api design imho.

Comment: @Vincent_Paing Can you provide a code sample of your approach?

Comment: Let's say you need to perform a couple of REST requests, some parsing, and write to db. For example, if you use Retrofit and Realm, you can write incapsulating class for this operation with clean synchronous code, and run it in one thread (since both APIs have sync and async methods), without interrupting the Main Thread many times (in my experience there were cases it caused some animations to freeze for a moment). And now you also need to get firebase token to perform this operation, it would be nice to have an option to make it synchronously, inside the same operation.

Answer (score 7):

I'm doing it like this now:

```
private suspend fun getTokenResult (firebaseUser: FirebaseUser) = suspendCoroutine<GetTokenResult?> { continuation ->
firebaseUser.getIdToken(true).addOnCompleteListener {
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        continuation.resume(it.result)
    } else {
        continuation.resume(null)
    }
}
```

Using a suspended function and the continuation mechanism. So if you are using `Coroutines`, this might be the easiest way

Comment: Glad to see this answer. Turning callback-based functions to suspend functions is one of my fav features. I don't see this being utilized enough.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I needed to update token in Retrofit Authenticator when I got 407. I use [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

```
override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
    val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    var token: String? = null
    val lock = CountDownLatch(1)

    user?.getIdToken(true)?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            token = task.result?.token
            if (token == null) {
                lock.countDown()            //<--unlock 
                return@addOnCompleteListener
            }
            //save token
        } else {
            lock.countDown()                //<--unlock 
            return@addOnCompleteListener
        }
    }
    lock.await()                            //<--wait unlock 

    return if (token != null)
        response.request().newBuilder().header(AUTHORIZATION_KEY, token).build()
    else null
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have done this and It works perfectly.
This is the main class:

```
object FcmToken {
    @JvmStatic
    fun getToken(): String? {
        val task = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId
        try {
            val result = Tasks.await(task)
            return result.token
        } catch (e: ExecutionException) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("")
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("")
        }
    }
}
```

In the view model.

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val result = FcmToken.getToken(viewModelScope)
        Log.e("result", result.toString())
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, just move all your following operations like `headers.put(...)` into the `onComplete` block. Which will guarantee the execution order.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually make the main function an async Task instead of void, then you will not get the error when awaiting for the async task to complete