# Firebase async tasks to coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines

I have used the suspend routine builder to make the Firebase Tasks's move away from async listener based code to coroutine-based code.

This is my suspendcoroutine via which I achieve the coroutine behavior.

```
suspend fun <T> Task<T>.awaitTask(): T =
    suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
        addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                continuation.resume(task.result!!)//what to do if task.result is null
            } else {
                continuation.resumeWithException(task.exception!!)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how I invoke it

```
firebase.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userCredentials.email!!, userCredentials.password!!).awaitTask()
```

All works well until we execute a task which has a possibility of a null result. Like .

```
firebase.currentUser?.updateProfile(profileUpdates)?.awaitTask()
```

Here upon successfully updation , task.result is null. In that case what should be passed to continuation.resume?.

Comment: It might be duplicated, I think this is [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63870294/4690298).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your return type should be nullable because `Task.getResult()` is nullable:

```
suspend fun <T> Task<T>.await() : T? = ...
```

If you use it to get a non-nullable result, then enforce non-nullability at the use site and not inside the implementation.

However, why do you bother reimplementing this when it's already defined in [`kotlinx-coroutines-play-services`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/src/Tasks.kt)?

Comment: While debugging the crash occurs here itself.